# GCD - Tracking total number or asynchronous tasks

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to keep track of the current number of asynchronous network requests, and show an activity indicator only while there is one or more requests in progress. I'm using dispatch groups but I think I have a race condition between `dispatch_group_notify`'s block and my `closure` block, because I occasionally get a crash on the `dispatch_group_leave(taskGroup)` line:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I think that this occurs because when there are no more items in a dispatch group, it is sometimes not freed in time (set to `nil`), before it is used by a later request (instead of a new group being created). Then, the group immediately notified that it is empty, the callback closure is called, it is set to `nil`, but there is still an extra item that attempts to leave the now `nil` group.

---

I think the solution lies in making sure `dispatch_group_leave` fires its block immediately after the last `dispatch_group_leave` is trigged, i.e. before the `callback` closure.

I tried wrapping the `dispatch_group_leave` and `callback` code in separate `dispatch_sync` closures, then adding them to a custom serial queue, but the problem persisted in over 50% of all executions.

Wrapping the `callback` closure call in an `dispatch_async` on the main queue (as seen in the code below) helps, but the problem is still present in about 10% of all executions.

Here's my code (copy paste to a Playground to test):

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

// Allow for asynchronous execution to take as long as it likes
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// Background container view
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view

// Our activity indicator
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
activityIndicator.center = view.center

// Used to keep track of the number of current tasks
var taskGroup: dispatch_group_t!

// An async task that calls its callback after 2 to 5 seconds
func fireATask(callback: String -> Void) {

    if taskGroup == nil {
        print("Creating new dispatch group")
        taskGroup = dispatch_group_create()
        dispatch_group_enter(taskGroup)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        dispatch_group_notify(taskGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            taskGroup = nil
            print("All done!")
        }
    } else {
        print("Using existing dispatch group")
        dispatch_group_enter(taskGroup)
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {

        let delay = arc4random_uniform(1) + 2
        print("Task fired with [\(delay)] second delay.")
        let delayNanoseconds = Int64(UInt64(delay) * NSEC_PER_SEC)
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayNanoseconds), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            dispatch_group_leave(taskGroup) // Sometimes crashing here because taskGroup is nil

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // My attempt to make sure dispatch_group_notify is called before the callback
                callback("Task with [\(delay)] second delay finished!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I sometimes get good results:

```
Creating new dispatch group
Using existing dispatch group
Task fired with [2] second delay.
Task fired with [2] second delay.
Task with [2] second delay finished!
All done!
Task with [2] second delay finished!
Creating new dispatch group
Task fired with [2] second delay.
All done!
Task with [2] second delay finished!
```

And other times I get the crash:

```
Creating new dispatch group
Using existing dispatch group
Task fired with [2] second delay.
Task fired with [2] second delay.
Task with [2] second delay finished!
Using existing dispatch group
Task fired with [2] second delay.
All done!
Task with [2] second delay finished!
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: 1. Why do you care whether dispatch_group_notify is called before the callback? 2. Why is the fireATask function responsible for making the dispatch_group? Can you just use one persistent group?

Comment: 2) because AFAIK, a dispatch group can only be used once, so once it fires I set it to `nil` and recreate it. 1) dispatch_group_notify need to be called first because when I'm leaving the group for the last time, I need it to recreate the group, before calling the callback which may invoke other fireATask calls (which in turn attempt to enter the current group).

Comment: To add to 2) I'm using this code to handle the network activity indicator in once central location for calls from anywhere in an app. As long as I keep firing fireATask requests, it should show the indicator, but when all requests have finished, and no more have been added, the activity indicator should go away.

Comment: A dispatch group seems too complicated to me.  I would implements functions `incrementActivityCount` and `decrementActivityCount`.  These functions should Immediately dispatch async onto the main queue a closure that either increments or decrements a counter. If the count decrements to 0, stop the activity view. If the count increments to 1, start animating

Comment: Agree with @Paulw11. But if you want to avoid your crash, change `taskGroup` to an optional and `if let` unwrap it each time you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dispatch_group_notify` schedules a block object to be submitted to a queue when the group is empty. Thus in your second example you get the crash. The messages in your log appear out-of-order because of calling print from different threads asynchronously. Here is the real situation:

```
Creating new dispatch group
Using existing dispatch group
Task fired with [2] second delay.
Task fired with [2] second delay.
Task with [2] second delay finished!
Task with [2] second delay finished!
All done!

Using existing dispatch group
Task fired with [2] second delay.
Task with [2] second delay finished!
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Just wrap all `print` calls with `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())` and you'll get something similar.

Here the way I'd solve the issue:

```
// The execution queue
var tasksQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)
var nTasks = 0

// An async task that calls its callback after 2 to 5 seconds
func fireATask(callback: String -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(tasksQueue) {

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            nTasks += 1
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }

        let delay = arc4random_uniform(1) + 2
        print("Task fired with [\(delay)] second delay.")
        let delayNanoseconds = Int64(UInt64(delay) * NSEC_PER_SEC)
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayNanoseconds), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            callback("Task with [\(delay)] second delay finished!")
            nTasks -= 1
            if nTasks == 0 {
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                print("All done!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a great solution to the problem, thanks! I still don't understand however, how to fix my code (using dispatch groups). By the way, did you mean `dispatch_async` instead of `dispatch_sync` for the print messages?

Comment: You don't need GCD groups here.  The `dispatch_group_notify` sets a callback that is invoked once. In your case you might have an empty queue from time to time when there is a gap between tasks. Take into account that log messages might appear out-of-order because of async nature of `dispatch_group_notify`, `dispatch_async` & `dispatch_after`.

Comment: I think the takeaway point here is that after a dispatch group receives its last `dispatch_group_leave` (i.e. the number of `dispatch_group_leave`s has equaled the number of `dispatch_group_enter`s), `dispatch_group_notify` does not call its handler synchronously (i.e. straightaway), it calls it asynchronously after an arbitrary amount of time. And I have found no way to change this behaviour.